# Call Foundry API from Typescript Function

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

Can we call a Foundry Developer API from a Typescript Function? If yes, can you please provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The current setup doesn't work quite like that (i.e. calling an endpoint from directly within a Typescript Function). Instead the connection configuration is set up Data Connection (this can be to an internal Foundry API or to an external API) and then configured as a [Webhook in a Foundry Action](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/webhooks/).

The Webhook *parameters* can be generated by a Typescript Function and the whole thing can then be, for example, wired into a button in a Workshop module.

There's sample code and more details in the documentation [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/webhooks/#:%7E:text=an%20object%20parameter.-,When,-using%20a%20Function).